# How to print array of objects using map method

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, methods

I am trying to read array of objects using map method in react js but every time I am getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
  const sellerinfo=props.sellerinfo.map(seller=>(
    <Seller
      key={seller.email}
      email={seller.first_name}/>
  ))
```

Comment: Can you post more of your component . The error is saying `sellerinfo` is undefined

Comment: export const fetchSellers = () => {
return dispatch => {
  dispatch(fetchSellersStart());
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/admin/listSellers',{
  headers: {
  Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
  }
})
  .then(response=>{
    const fetchSellersVar=[];
    for(let key in response.data){
      fetchSellersVar.push({
        ...response.data[key],
        id:key
      });
    }
    dispatch(fetchSellersSuccess(fetchSellersVar));
  }).catch(error=>{
    dispatch(fetchSellerFail(error));
  });
};
};

Comment: const seller=(props)=>{
const listSeller=[];
for(let sellerDetails in props.listSeller){
    listSeller.push({email:sellerDetails,first_name:props.listSeller[sellerDetails]
    }
  );
  }
  const sellerOutput=listSeller.map(ig=>{
    return <span
    key={ig.email}>
    {ig.email}
    {ig.first_name}
  </span>;
  });

Comment: @user5474425 please add the requested code to your original post instead of in a comment as it will be easier to read and relevant to your question.

Comment: We don't know what props are being passed, but perhaps it's a simple typo?  Might it be `sellerInfo` (camel case with a capital "I") rather than `sellerinfo` (all lowercase)?

Comment: I am not able to paste code in code section that's why I pasted it here you can look at the screen shot I have attached it is returning array of objects

Comment: @user5474425  Are you still looking for an answer of this?